# Lists of summaries from rentrez stop working after being merged using append()

Tags: r, append, rentrez

tl;dr: What is different about an esummary list produced by `rentrez`, and why do said lists stop working with other `rentrez` functions after they are merged using `append()`?

I am accessing Pubmed using `rentrez`. I am able to search for publications and download esummaries without problem. However, there must be something special about an esummary list that I do not understand, because things fall apart when I used `append()` to try to merge lists. I have not been able to figure out what that difference is by reading the documentation. Here is the code that allows me to search Pubmed and download records without problem:

```
# set search term and retmax
term_set <- '"Transcription, Genetic"[Mesh] AND "Regulatory Sequences, Nucleic Acid"[Mesh] AND 2017:2018[PDAT]'
retmax_set <- 500
# search pubmed using web history
search.l <- entrez_search(db = "pubmed", term = term_set, use_history = T)
# get summaries of search hits using web history 
for (seq_start in seq(0, search.l$count, retmax_set)) {
    if (seq_start == 0) {summary.l <- list()} 
    summary.l[[length(summary.l)+1]] <- entrez_summary(
        db = "pubmed", 
        web_history = search.l$web_history, 
        retmax = retmax_set, 
        retstart = seq_start
    )
}
```

However, using `summary.l <- list()` and then `summary.l[[length(summary.l)+1]] <- entrez_summary(...` results in a list of lists of esummaries (3 sub-lists, in this search). This results in multiple `for` loops in subsequent steps of the data extraction (below) and is an unweildly data structure.

```
# extract desired information from esummary, convert to dataframe
for (i in 1:length(summary.l)) {
    if (i == 1) {faut.laut.l <- list()}
    faut.laut <- summary.l[[i]] %>% 
        extract_from_esummary(
            c("uid", "sortfirstauthor", "lastauthor"), 
            simplify = F
        )
    faut.laut.l <- c(faut.laut.l, faut.laut)
}
faut.laut.df <- rbindlist(faut.laut.l)
```

Using `append()` in the code below gives a single list of all 1334 esummaries, avoiding the sub-lists.

```
# get summaries of search hits using web history 
for (seq_start in seq(0, search.l$count, retmax_set)) {
    if (seq_start == 0) {
        summary.append.l <- entrez_summary(
            db = "pubmed", 
            web_history = search.l$web_history, 
            retmax = retmax_set, 
            retstart = seq_start
        )
    } 
    summary.append.l <- append(
        summary.append.l,
        entrez_summary(
            db = "pubmed", 
            web_history = search.l$web_history, 
            retmax = retmax_set, 
            retstart = seq_start
        )
    )
}
```

However, in the subsequent step `extract_from_esummary()` throws an error, even though the documentation says states that the argument `esummaries` should be a list of esummary objects.

```
# extract desired information from esummary, convert to dataframe
faut.laut.append.l <- extract_from_esummary(
    esummaries = summary.append.l,
    elements = c("uid", "sortfirstauthor", "lastauthor"), 
    simplify = F
)
Error in UseMethod("extract_from_esummary", esummaries) : 
no applicable method for 'extract_from_esummary' applied to an object of class "list"

faut.laut.append.df <- rbindlist(faut.laut.append.l)
Error in rbindlist(faut.laut.append.l) : 
object 'faut.laut.append.l' not found
```

A search that yeilds less than 500 records can be done in a single call of `entrez_summary()` and does not require the concatenation of lists. As a result, the code below works.

```
# set search term and retmax
term_set_small <- 'kadonaga[AUTH]'
retmax_set <- 500
# search pubmed using web history
search_small <- entrez_search(db = "pubmed", term = term_set_small, use_history = T)
# get summaries from search with <500 hits
summary_small <- entrez_summary(
    db = "pubmed", 
    web_history = search_small$web_history, 
    retmax = retmax_set
)
# extract desired information from esummary, convert to dataframe
faut.laut_small <- extract_from_esummary(
    esummaries = summary_small,
    elements = c("uid", "sortfirstauthor", "lastauthor"), 
    simplify = F
)
faut.laut_small.df <- rbindlist(faut.laut_small)
```

Why does `append()` break the esummaries, and can this be avoided? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `extract_from_esummary` is a little confusing on this. What it really needs is either an `esummary` object or an `esummary_list`. Because the `esummary` object itself inherits from a list I don't think we can easily have `extract_from_esummary` work on any list that is thrown at it. I'll fix the docs and maybe think about a better design for the objects.

To fix this particular problem there are a few fixes. One, you can just re-class the list of esummaries

```
class(summary.append.l) <- c("list", "esummary_list")
extract_from_esummary(summary.append.l, "sortfirstauthor")
```

Should do the trick. Another option would be to extract the relevant data before you do any appending. This is something simlar to your example with more `lapply` and less `for`

```
all_the_summs <- lapply(seq(0,50,5),  function(s) {
    entrez_summary(db="pubmed", 
                   web_history=search.l$web_history, 
                   retmax=5,  retstart=s)
})
desired_fields <- lapply(all_the_summs, extract_from_esummary, c("uid", "sortfirstauthor", "lastauthor"), simplify=FALSE)  
res <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, desired_fields)
```

Hope that provides a way forward.

Comment: class(summary.append.l) <- c("esummary_list", "list") worked perfectly! I'm still trying to understand all of the levels to how R classifies object. Thank you for your help.

Comment: object orientation in R is a bit different than many other languages, and can be confusing! Hadley's book has nice summary of this system, if you want to get a feel for what's going on http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S3.html